# Is there a way to skip python unit test case in setUpClasss without raising exception?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Right now the way is to use "raise unittest.SkipTest('Exception message')".
But this shows the exception in the test result.

Is there a way we can have 0 exception 0 failures when test case is skipped in setUpClass()?

Comment: Why not just comment out the test?

Comment: I want to run the tests depending on some condition. If the condition is not met, I don;t want to run the tests, so want to skip all tests through setUpClass.

Comment: Ah, I see. Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures) *"If there are any exceptions raised during one of the shared fixture functions the test is reported as an error"*. Can you not use [`skipIf`/`skipUnless`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures)?

Comment: yes, thinking the same now. I was looking for one liner solution and did not want to touch the test cases.